# What is the name of this horror movie with ceiling crawling monsters?

Tags: story-identification, horror

So I watched a movie a few years ago, it came out in at least 2008 . It was a horror movie where there were creatures crawling on the ceiling and the only way to fend them off was with light. They could shape shift and the way the mother in the story dies because she trusted the creatures and turned off her light. I can't remember it and I just need to remember the movie.

Comment: Can you recall anything else about the movie? There are a lot of movies with crawling creatures on the ceiling that are afraid of light, though the mother “trusting” them is a good detail. Did she trust someone who was being impersonated by a shapeshifting creature?

Comment: Some things come to mind. Are the protagonists childhood friends in their twenties, all suffering from night terrors? Do they discover that they are somehow "marked"?

Comment: "it came out in at least 2008" as in it may have come out before 2008? Or it must have come out in 2008 or later?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall a part with creatures crawling on the ceiling, but the rest of your description seems to fit well with the movie "Darkness" from 2002.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0273517/

The shapeshifting creatures in the movie are some kind of personification of Darkness and can only kill things if it is completely dark. There is a scene where the mother is alone with the Darkness disguised as her two kids trying to convince her that everything will be alright if she just turns out the lights.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the film you are referring to is 'Lights Out'. A film with a similar theme is 'Wes Craven Presents: They'.
On second thought it can't be 'Lights Out'. That film is too recent to be the movie you are referring to.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Could you [edit] your answer to provide some details how *Lights Out* matches the question?  Is there a scene with a mother being convinced to turn off her light?  Please read [answer], and you might want to take the [tour].

Comment: It could still be Lights Out, you’d be surprised how people misremember dates. However, I’d be incredibly surprised with this being asked a couple months after the release date (If I checked the right film). Though per the above could you [edit] this to explain how it matches?